# Configuring jobs with parameters in quartz.net xml job definition file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, quartz.net

I have a job which that has a constructor that contains parameters and I was wondering if there was away to configure quartz to instantiate the object by passing a parameter defined in the jobs configuration file. I've tried using the job-data-map element but that doesn't appear to work. Is this at all possible?

Thanks

Comment: I can not understand your problem? can you give some more description about this issue?

Comment: when i use the configuration file to configure my jobs i keep getting a Quartz.SchedulerException for any jobs that have a non-empty constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jobs must have a constructor that does not require parameters. In order to pass parameters to a job via xml, use xml like this:

```
<job>
  <name>nativeJobExample</name>
  <group>nativeJobExampleGroup</group>
  <description>Sample job for Quartz Server</description>
  <job-type>Quartz.Job.NativeJob, Quartz</job-type>
  <job-data-map>
    <entry>
      <key>command</key>
      <value>native_job_example.bat</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key>consumeStreams</key>
      <value>true</value>
    </entry>
  </job-data-map>
</job>
```

Then you can access the data through the data map that is passed in to the job's execute method:

```
    public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobDataMap data = context.MergedJobDataMap;

        string command = data.GetString(PropertyCommand);
```